# Updating component state in React-Redux with API calls

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to set up a React app where clicking a map marker in one component re-renders another component on the page with data from the database and changes the URL. It works, sort of, but not well.
I'm having trouble figuring out how getting the state from Redux and getting a response back from the API fit within the React life cycle.

There are two related problems:

FIRST: The commented-out line "//APIManager.get()......" doesn't work, but the hacked-together version on the line below it does.

SECOND: The line where I'm console.log()-ing the response logs infinitely and makes infinite GET requests to my database.

Here's my component below:

```
class Hike extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      currentHike: {
        id: '',
        name: '',
        review: {},
      }
    }
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    const params = this.props.params
    const hack = "/api/hike/" + params
    // APIManager.get('/api/hike/', params, (err, response) => { // doesn't work
    APIManager.get(hack, null, (err, response) => { // works
      if (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return
      }
      console.log(JSON.stringify(response.result)) // SECOND

      this.setState({
        currentHike: response.result
      })
    })
  }

  render() {
    // Allow for fields to be blank
    const name = (this.state.currentHike.name == null) ? null : this.state.currentHike.name

    return (
      <div>
        <p>testing hike component</p>
        <p>{this.state.currentHike.name}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const stateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    params: state.hike.selectedHike
  }
}

export default connect(stateToProps)(Hike)
```

Also: When I click a link on the page to go to another url, I get the following error:

```
"Warning: setState(...): Can only update a mounted or mounting component. This usually means you called setState() on an unmounted component. This is a no-op."
```

Comment: it's making infinite calls to your db because you call the API in `componentDidUpdate`, and then you set the state again from the response of the API, which causes the `componentDidUpdate` hook to fire again.

Answer (score 5):

Looking at your code, I think I would architect it slightly differently

Few things:

1. Try to move the API calls and fetch data into a Redux action. Since API fetch is asynchronous, I think it is best to use [Redux Thunk](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)

example:

```
function fetchHikeById(hikeId) {
    return dispatch => {
        // optional: dispatch an action here to change redux state to loading
        dispatch(action.loadingStarted())
        const hack = "/api/hike/" + hikeId
        APIManager.get(hack, null, (err, response) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                // if you want user to know an error happened.
                // you can optionally dispatch action to store
                // the error in the redux state. 
                dispatch(action.fetchError(err));
                return;
             }
             dispatch(action.currentHikeReceived(response.result))
        });
    } 
}
```

You can map dispatch to props for fetchHikeById also, by treating fetchHikeById like any other action creator.

2. Since you have a path `/hike/:hikeId` I assume you are also updating the route. So if you want people to book mark and save and url `.../hike/2` or go back to it. You can still put the the fetch in the Hike component.

The lifecycle method you put the fetchHikeById action is.

```
componentDidMount() {
    // assume you are using react router to pass the hikeId 
    // from the url '/hike/:hikeId' 
    const hikeId = this.props.params.hikeId;
    this.props.fetchHikeById(hikeId);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
   // so this is when the props changed.
   // so if the hikeId change, you'd have to re-fetch.  
   if (this.props.params.hikeId !== nextProps.params.hikeId) {
       this.props.fetchHikeById(nextProps.params.hikeId)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any Redux being used at all in your code. If you plan on using Redux, you should move all that API logic into an action creator and store the API responses in your Redux Store. I understand you're quickly prototyping now. :)

Your infinite loop is caused because you chose the wrong lifecycle method. If you use the `componentDidUpdate` and `setState`, it will again cause the `componentDidUpdate`method to be called and so on. You're basically updating whenever the component is updated, if that makes any sense. :D

You could always check, before sending the API call, if the new `props.params` you have are different than the ones you previously had (which caused the API call). You receive the old props and state as arguments to that function.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate

However, if you've decided to use Redux, I would probably move that logic to an action creator, store that response in your Redux Store and simply use that data in your `connect`.

Comment: I'm using Redux so that the component on the left side of the page can share data with the component on the right. I'm trying to get the state of the right component to update and change the URL while the left component remains the same.

Comment: As I said, if you want to use componentDidUpdate, you need to check if you really need to perform the API call again. Otherwise you're in a loop. If you used Redux properly, you wouldn't have the `setState` calls you have, and you wouldn't be facing this problem. Also, I don't see in your example the "left" component so I can't help you further.

Comment: You were right that I didn't need to perform the API call there. I moved it out into another component and it worked. My fix with both components in a comment below, but I'm still not sure if it's best Redux practices.

Answer (score 1):

The FIRST problem I cannot help with, as I do not know what this APIManager's arguments should be.

The SECOND problem is a result of you doing API requests in "componentDidUpdate()". This is essentially what happens:

1. Some state changes in redux.
2. Hike receives new props (or its state changes).
3. Hike renders according to the new props.
4. Hike has now been updated and calls your "componentDidUpdate" function.
5. componentDidUpdate makes the API call, and when the response comes back, it triggers setState().
6. Inner state of Hike is changed, which triggers an update of the component(!) -> goto step 2.

When you click on a link to another page, the infinite loop is continued and after the last API call triggered by an update of Hike is resolved, you call "setState" again, which now tries to update the state of a no-longer-mounted component, hence the warning.

[The docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html) explain this really well I find, I would give those a thorough read.

Answer (score 0):

Try making the API call in `componentDidMount`:

```
componentDidMount() {
  // make your API call and then call .setState
}
```

Do that instead of inside of `componentDidUpdate`.

There are many ways to architect your API calls inside of your React app. For example, take a look at this article: [React AJAX Best Practices](http://andrewhfarmer.com/react-ajax-best-practices/). In case the link is broken, it outlines a few ideas:

> **Root Component**
>
> This is the simplest approach so it's great for prototypes and small apps.
>
> With this approach, you build a single root/parent component that issues all your AJAX requests. The root component stores the AJAX response data in it's state, and passes that state (or a portion of it) down to child components as props.

As this is outside the scope of the question, I'll leave you to to a bit of research, but some other methods for managing state and async API calls involved libraries like [Redux](http://redux.js.org/) which is one of the de-facto state managers for React right now.

By the way, your infinite calls come from the fact that when your component updates, it's making an API call and then calling `setState` which updates the component again, throwing you into an infinite loop.

Comment: I tried componentDidUpdate() but it leads to same problem of infinite GET requests

Comment: @crashspringfield did you mean `componentDidMount`? `componentDidUpdate` seems like it's at fault for the infinite requests.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. componentDidMount renders it once. The problem is I have a left and right component and I want the left one to control the state of the right one. If I use componentDidMount, it renders once but doesn't respond to changes from the left component.

Comment: @crashspringfield can you update your question with the architecture you currently have (for example, the "left side" "right side" thing confuses me a bit; it would be helpful to see a full example. Just need the skeleton of the code.)

Comment: I took the API call out of this component and put it in another and that seemed to do the trick. I posted how I reworked this component into another.

Answer (score 0):

Still figuring out the flow of Redux because it solved the problem when I moved the API request from the Hike component to the one it was listening to.
Now the Hike component is just listening and re-rendering once the database info catches up with the re-routing and re-rendering.

Hike.js

```
class Hike extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {}
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
     console.log('dealing with ' + JSON.stringify(this.props.currentHike))
  }

  render() {

    if (this.props.currentHike == null || undefined) { return false }
    const currentHike = this.props.currentHike

    return (
      <div className="sidebar">
        <p>{currentHike.name}</p>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

const stateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    currentHike: state.hike.currentHike,
  }
}
```

And "this.props.currentHikeReceived()" got moved back to the action doing everything in the other component so I no longer have to worry about the Hikes component infinitely re-rendering itself.

Map.js

```
onMarkerClick(id) {
    const hikeId = id
    // Set params to be fetched
    this.props.hikeSelected(hikeId)
    // GET hike data from database
    const hack = "/api/hike/" + hikeId
    APIManager.get(hack, null, (err, response) => {
      if (err) {
        console.error(err)
        return
      }
      this.props.currentHikeReceived(response.result)
    })
    // Change path to clicked hike
    const path = `/hike/${hikeId}`
    browserHistory.push(path)
  }

const stateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    hikes: state.hike.list,
    location: state.newHike
  }
}

const dispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
    currentHikeReceived: (hike) => dispatch(actions.currentHikeReceived(hike)),
    hikesReceived: (hikes) => dispatch(actions.hikesReceived(hikes)),
    hikeSelected: (hike) => dispatch(actions.hikeSelected(hike)),
    locationAdded: (location) => dispatch(actions.locationAdded(location)),
    }
}
```